# Submit for Review for Testflight (iOS)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I want to send out my App for external Beta Tests so i want to use Apple's new TestFlight System for this.

I managed to invite internal tester yet and they can test the app, so i found out that i have to submit the app for external beta testing.

If i log into iTunes Connect i dont see the option to submit for "TestFlight" i only see the "Submit for Review" button that i can use to submit to the AppStore, or is it the same?

Anyone maybe can explain a bit more about how to use and submit the external Beta Test of TestFlight?

Comment: Did you see the new "Prerelease" tab in iTunesConnect? Everything is explained here

Comment: Yes i do and as i sad internal tester works great, but still i dont see the "Review" Button for submit for review for external tester at the prerelease tab @JoëlSalamin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find more info about Beta Testing here: [AppStore - TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/). As mentioned on this page, the public Beta Testing feature is not yet available:

> **External Testers (Coming Soon)**

Comment: *doh* thanks ... i thought it already working - as i saw some people submit it already

Answer (score 2):

External testing just went live.  Adding an external tester is as simple as adding their email address in the External Tester section.  See screenshot from itunesConnect.  To request review for beta, go to the Builds tab and select "submit for beta review" for the build you want to submit.

Submission for Review:

[image: Submit for beta review link]

Adding beta users:
[image: iTunes Connect Screenshot]

Comment: How long does it take to get a beta app reviewed?

Comment: They must comply with the full app store review guidelines so I expect the timeline to be similar. I have not submitted yet.

Comment: That's great.  I assume you had all of the usual suspects lined up already, privacy policy URLs, etc. i.e. the criteria felt the same as for the full review?

Comment: My privacy policy has a 404 and some other things were not in place, but they seemed ok with it. I had a button there but with a blank webview so i guess it shows intent.

Answer (score 0):

This guide gives a walkthrough and a video about the new testing process with Testflight and internal testers: http://blog.thebetafamily.com/2014/09/10/testflight-beta-testing-ios-8/

The feature for external testers will as mentioned "come soon", I think it will be in a near future, hopefully today together with the iOS 8.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

Under the pre-release section, against your build you should see a link called Submit for Beta Review.